# ASP MVC Download Zip Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetzip

i have a view where i put the id of the event then i can download all the images for that event.....
here's my code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection All)
    {
        try
        {
            var context = new MyEntities();

            var Im = (from p in context.Event_Photos
                      where p.Event_Id == 1332
                      select p.Event_Photo);

            Response.Clear();

            var downloadFileName = string.Format("YourDownload-{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + downloadFileName);

            using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile())
            {
                zipFile.AddDirectoryByName("Files");
                foreach (var userPicture in Im)
                {
                    zipFile.AddFile(Server.MapPath(@"\") + userPicture.Remove(0, 1), "Files");
                }
                zipFile.Save(Response.OutputStream);

                //Response.Close();
            }
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that each time i get html page to download so instead of downloading "Album.zip" i get "Album.html" any ideas???

Comment: Debug to check if `downloadFileName` contains `.zip` extension..

Comment: It Contains .zip
here's what is in it "YourDownload-2013-03-13-15_04_20.zip"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In MVC, rather than returning a view, if you want to return a file, you can return this as an `ActionResult` by doing:

```
return File(zipFile.GetBytes(), "application/zip", downloadFileName);
// OR
return File(zipFile.GetStream(), "application/zip", downloadFileName);
```

Don't mess about with manually writing to the output stream if you're using MVC.

I'm not sure if you can get the bytes or the stream from the `ZipFile` class though. Alternatively, you might want it to write it's output to a `MemoryStream` and then return that:

```
 var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition {
     FileName = downloadFileName,
     Inline = false, 
};
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
var memStream = new MemoryStream();
zipFile.Save(memStream);
memStream.Position = 0; // Else it will try to read starting at the end
return File(memStream, "application/zip");
```

And by using this, you can remove all lines in which you are doing anything with the `Response`. No need to `Clear` or `AddHeader`.

Comment: I only worked when i replaced "application/zip" with "application/octet-stream" even in my code.
also zipFile.GetBytes() gives an error

Comment: I Have another problem no, the .zip file contain the whole path of the file i want only the images to be in the zip file??
how could i do that??

Comment: I didn't know the specifics of the DotNetZip library, which is what I said in my answer, and which is why I added the second solution (writing it to a MemoryStream and return that). I will add a line to force download rather than inline.

Comment: Regarding the file paths, feel free to open a seperate question on this site for that.

Comment: The `ContentDisposition` still should not be needed I believe. It will serve it as a file and not as a page, so the users browser should never just show this as a page. Especially with `"application/zip"` as a content type. (But then you will have to add the filename to the call to `File` to have right name show up).

Comment: Now, i want to Just download the Images in the zip file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if it's not related to actually showing you a file download (the problem was that you were presented some sort of html rather than a zip), you might want to open a new separate question.

Comment: @RenéWolferink : why u use zipFile.Save(memStream); ? it will save zip file in memory. if size would be huge very big then program may crash.

Comment: "memStream.Position = 0;" really helped me, thanks. I have been still recieving blank zip and couldnt understand why.