# ZipArchive Created with System.IO.Compression is Damaged

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, c#-ziparchive

I am having a hard time creating a ZipArchive successfully on Asp.net core MVC. I have an excel file generated with data that works and I need to put in an archive. This is what I've done so far

```
        public FileResult ExportGoodsReceiptData()
        {
            var records = _salesService.GetAllReceipts();
            var lineRecords = _salesService.GetAllReceiptLines();
            var result = _salesService.ExportGoodsReceiptData(records);
            var lineResult = _salesService.ExportGoodsReceiptLineData(lineRecords);

            byte[] resultArr = StreamToByteArray(result);
            byte[] lineResultArr = StreamToByteArray(lineResult);

            using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry("GoodsReceipts.csv", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                    using (var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open())
                    using (var resultCom = new MemoryStream(resultArr))
                    {
                        resultCom.CopyTo(zipStream);
                    }
                }

                return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = "GoodsReceiptsArchive.zip" };
            }
        }
```

When I run it, I get the zipfile, but can't open it. It throws error stating that it may have been damaged. I debugged the code to notice that one of the properties (length property) throws an invalidOperation exception. My approach looks identical to most samples I found online. Don't know how else to solve this.

Comment: Call .Dispose on your zipArchiveEntry variable to close the entry.

Comment: @JayBuckman The Dispose() method does not exist in the object.

Comment: Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907291/downloading-of-zip-file-through-asp-net-mvc-using-dotnetzip  Try removing the using from MemoryStream stream

Comment: @WithMetta I already tried the approach of removing the using directive on memorystream and I got nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I meant call it on the archive object.

Comment: You're disposing of the memory stream as you return it.  The `FileStreamResult` effectively contains no data because the stream gets disposed.

Comment: @JayBuckman still didn't work. Although with the using directive, I don't think the Dispose() call is necessary

Comment: @Amy No he's not.  ** n/m I think the question was edited.

Comment: Yes, the question was clearly edited...

Comment: Yes. @KaceyEzerioha, you shouldn't edit in partial answers. Probably why your getting downvotes, it lets Amy's answer dangle in the air.  I'll roll back. You can _add_ a section with a second version but that's not too important here.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by editing partial answers.

Comment: You removed the using() that was the core of Amy's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're disposing of your memory stream before you return it.  Remove this `using`:

```
using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
```

Replace it with:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
```

Asp.Net MVC will automatically dispose of the stream for you.

Comment: I tried it as someone suggested earlier but it still gave me a damaged zip file.

Comment: Nevertheless, you do need to make this change.

Comment: My current code has the change. I'm just yet to make the update on the question.