# Download zip file from webapp

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

The user of my webapp should be able to download a zip-file with more than 10MB.
I have the following code in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Download(){
    Response.Clear();
    esponse.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename +".zip");
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.SendFileAsync(pathOfTheFile);
    Response.Body.FlushAsync();

    return Content("Download successfull");
}
```

It starts downloading the file but the download stops an it says network error.
When I say continue in the download-bar, it says that there is no file.

What is my problem?

Comment: try this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385958/asp-mvc-download-zip-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because response with headers and content is written twice. First time it's written by your code including `Response.Body.FlushAsync` and second time it's written by `ASP.NET` framework when result returned by action is executed (`IActionResult.ExecuteResultAsync`).

Consider using `File` method provided by `Controller`

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Download()
{
    byte[] content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathOfTheFile);

    return File(content, "application/zip", filename);
}
```

Comment: It would be appreciated to describe your answer and why the original code doesn't work rather than just posting copy & paste ready code. The reason the OPs code isn't working cause he is sending a `ContentResult` back which will try to write headers after the file was sent (which isn't possible, as headers need to be sent before the content)