# Downloading zip file from controller is not showing download or any errors

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.file

> I am trying to put a list of file paths into a zip file and download them in my controller but nothing is happening. I haven't gotten any errors and nothing pops up as downloaded after executing the program.
>
> Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    
    public ActionResult ExportFile(ClientStatement_Inventory model, string[] years, string[] months, string[] radio, string[] emails, string acctNum)
    {
        List<string> allPaths = new List<string>();
        
        // Is Account Number empty or Radio not selected
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(acctNum.Trim()) && radio == null)
        {

            return Json(new { success = false, message = "* Please Enter Account Number\n\n * Please choose whether to download or email statements" });

        }
        if (acctNum == "")
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "* Please Enter Account Number" });

        }
        else if (radio == null)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "* Please Choose whether To Download or Email" });
        }

        //try
        //{

        // If months and years are selected
        if (months != null)
        {
            if (years != null)
            {
                using (var db = new DB())
                {
                    // Get Specific years and months
                    allPaths = db.ClientStatement_Inventory
                                           .Where(x => x.accountNum == acctNum && years.Contains(x.statementYear) && months.Contains(x.statementMonth))
                                           .Select(c => c.statementPath).ToList();
                }

                if (allPaths.Count == 0)
                {
                    return Json(new { success = false, message = $"* There were no documents for Account#: {acctNum}" });
                }

            }
            //return View();
        }
        
        //Downloading Statements is chosen
        if (radio[0] == "Download Statements")
            {
                foreach (var path in allPaths)
                {
                    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                    var result = fileBytes;
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName("sjdfk.pdf");
                    string realpath = Server.MapPath("~/Downloads");
                    string fullPath = Path.Combine(realpath, filename);
                    string contentType = "application/zip";
                    string file = builder.ToString();
                    return File(fullPath, contentType, "Helo");
                }
            }

        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    //error
        //    return Redirect("Home/Index");
        //}
        return Redirect("Home/Index");
        
    }
}
```

}

> If you see my comment //Downloading statement is chosen. Thats where I am trying to download the files. I know my foreach loop is very wrong but nothing is happening I can't even get and error or one file to download.
> Also my allPaths variable is an array of multiple strings of the server path name of the files. so they would look like \ipt-siru1\filename
> I just don't know what else to try. I've tried so many different things today and still can't get this figured out.

Comment: Are you able debug your code? Code of line `return File(fullPath...` is executed? You have file returned in foreach loop, that means you want to download multiple files?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes i have debugged and stepped through all my code and can't see any errors on anything. I was told i need to handle the download on client side using javascript but have no idea how to do that. 

And I know the foreach is wrong and everything shouldn't be in that loop but it should at least download one file but I can't even get that.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/download-files-in-zip-formate-in-mvc-net/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385958/asp-mvc-download-zip-files

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thank you for the info but I have already been to both of those pages. I have done too much research and nothing is working. Everyone shows that the return File() in the action should return the file alone. Now I was just told by a friend that I need to handle it with javascript. It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You are reading the bytes from path but not using them anywhere. You are creating variables with file name and fullpath but saving file using them. You are just returning file object using full path. Also there is nowhere in the code you are generating zip file. I feel problem lies there. You might want to remove loop and use only one file, write proper code to create zip and try to return it as file object. The links I shared has examples of generating zip files on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't tested this but you could try something like this to save it into the memorystream:

```
var downloadFileName = string.Format("YourDownload-{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss"));
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + downloadFileName);
        
        using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zipFile = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
        {
            zipFile.AddDirectoryByName("Files");
            foreach (var path in allPaths)
            {
                
                zipFile.AddFile(path);
            }
            //zipFile.Save(Response.OutputStream);
            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = downloadFileName,
                Inline = false,
            };
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            var memStream = new MemoryStream();
            zipFile.Save(memStream);
            memStream.Position = 0; // Else it will try to read starting at the end
            return File(memStream, "application/octet-stream");
            //Response.Close();
        }
```